# Синтаксис. Пояснительные и присоединительные конструкции

Tags: синтаксис

Как подчеркиваются на письме пояснительные, присоединительные члены?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно определить, какой это член предложения, так и подчёркивать.

*Особенно нам, русским, должна быть близка и драгоценна сжатость (Чернышевский).*
Русским - приложение, подчёркиваем волнистой чертой, как определение.

*Ему представился свой дом – шесть больших комнат (М. Горький)* — приложение.

*Иногда что-нибудь хочется сделать – почитать (Гоголь).* — поясняет сказуемое и подчёркивается как сказуемое.

*Астрономы наблюдали вспышки особых, так называемых новых, звёзд.* — поясняющее определение.

*В то время, именно год назад, я сотрудничал по журналам.* — поясняющее обстоятельство.

*Было тепло, даже жарко. Даже жарко.* — присоединительное сказуемое.

*Что тут прикажешь делать скульптору, да ещё плохому?* — присоединительное определение.

Comment: В итоге присоединительной и пояснительной конструкцией может быть абсолютно любой обособленный член, будь то приложение, согласованные и несогласованные определения, уточняющие члены?

Comment: Да,любой член предложения, только уточняющий член нужно отличать от поясняющего. Уточняющий всегда такой же, как тот член предложения, который он уточняет, просто сужает смысл слова или словосочетания, поясняющий член - то же самое другими словами. Подлежащее обычно поясняется приложением. Присоединительный может быть совсем другим членом предложения, нужно задавать вопрос и  в каждом конкретном случае определять его роль в предложении.

Comment: Спасибо большое!